# How to update schema by adding Annotated classes to an existing Persistence unit in JPA with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

Environment: JPA 2.0, Hibernate 3.6, in a war file (with jsf 2.0, on jboss 6, etc).
I want update schema by adding Annotated classes to an existing Persistence unit in JPA with hibernate. this is what I have tried to do:

```
public void updateConfiguration() {
    // load classes
    Ejb3Configuration ejb3Configuration = new Ejb3Configuration();
    ejb3Configuration = ejb3Configuration.configure("existingPU", null);
    loadModel(ejb3Configuration);
    updateSchema(ejb3Configuration.getHibernateConfiguration());
}

private void updateSchema(Configuration cfg) {
    SchemaUpdate schemaUpdate = new SchemaUpdate(cfg);
    schemaUpdate.execute(true, true);
}

private void loadModel(Ejb3Configuration ejb3Configuration) {
    for (Object _object : objectList) {
        ejb3Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(_object.getClass());
    }

}
```

The `existingPU` is loaded by the normal JPA way using persistence.xml etc. The schema is updated for the entities in `WEB-INF/classes` and that part of the code base works perfectly. Now, the new classes in the `objectList` extend a `@MappedSuperclass` from `WEB-INF/classes` which has

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class OwnerHolder implements Serializable {
    private User owner;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_owner_id")
    public User getOwner() {
         return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(User owner) {
        this.owner= owner;
    }
}
```

This class is also extended by classes in WEB-INF/classes and that code works fine. The error I get is as follows:

```
13:36:45,494 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] could not complete schema update: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.myproject.external.model.PurchaseOrder.owner references an unknown entity: com.myproject.model.User
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:107) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1550) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1473) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1389) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateSchemaUpdateScript(Configuration.java:1160) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:187) [:3.6.0.Final]
at com.myproject.MyConfiguration.updateSchema(MyConfiguration.java:43) [:]
```

The `objectList` is list of classes from a jar file placed in WEB-INF/lib.

Can you please help me?

Comment: further progress: I reloaded all the Entities, including the ones previously loaded at startup, in `loadModel(Ejb3Configuration)` and it works fine. which basically means that the `Ejb3Configuration` that I have loaded does not have the entities in it which were loaded at startup. Any idea why that would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the User class hast the @Entity annotation in its declaration.

Comment: thank you @peshkira. I have checked all the checkpoints that you have mentioned. all are fine. as far as annotations are concerned they are consistently on the get property including `@Id` as mentioned in [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property). Also as mentioned before the code for the model inside `WEB-INF/classes` is working fine. there are about 20 classes inside `WEB-INF/classes` that extend `OwnerHolder` and all are fine. My inference: when I try to add a new Annotated class to the `existingPU` the old ones ain't there